# Django "after_db_save" signal

Tags: django

The post_save signal according to the documentation is "sent at the **end** of the save() method." but not **after** it.

### The Scenario

Model **A** 's `post_save` signal is being used to call another service which creates a Model **B** whose field **a_id** is a foreign key to model **A**. But the service is getting a error stating that the PK of Model **A** does not exist.

So is there a django signal which is triggered after the instance is saved in the database?

If no, how should I implement this functionality? I've read about using `transaction.on_commit()` but how would I use it inside the signal?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really get the transaction thing working but solved this problem by offloading the task into a task queue (`huey` in my case). Just make a function and decorate it with `@db_task` and call it inside the `post_save` signal.